# Qt QNetworkAccessManager & simple web service return

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

I have a simple web service with the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/WebSvc1/webresources/generic/data?ctype=Ping
```

This returns a simple XML data:

```
<CALL TYPE='Ping'><IP>10.0.0.10</IP></CALL>
```

I'm trying to write a Qt program to call this web service.

The code that makes the call is below:

```
  QUrl qrl("http://localhost:8080/WebSvc1/webresources/generic/data?ctype=Ping");
  manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
  connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
  printf ("Calling url: [%s]\n", qPrintable(url));
  QNetworkReply *reply = 0;
  reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(qrl));
  qDebug() << reply->readAll();
```

I'm expecting/hoping the readAll will get the XML text data and print it (via qDebug).

Instead I see nothing and the program just hangs.

UPpdate, also have this:

```
void obj::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
qDebug() << reply->readAll();
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure,so now I post comment. Try create slot replyFinished and IN this slot write qDebug()<< reply->readAll() Now ir works?

Comment: I've got this:

void iwbWSCall::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
qDebug() << reply->readAll();
}

But still no different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've included an example (forcing a synchronous request <-> reply exchange to easy the debugging process) that should work for you:

```
QUrl qrl("http://localhost:8080/WebSvc1/webresources/generic/data?ctype=Ping");
qDebug() << "Calling url: " << qrl.toString();
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(qrl));
QEventLoop eventLoop;
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
eventLoop.exec();
if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
{
    qDebug() << "Network error: " << reply->error();
}
else
{
    qDebug() << reply->readAll();
}
```

Notice that the "emitter" of the `finished` signal is not the `QNetworkAccessManager` but the `reply` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error could be with your web service. I tried your code out (slightly modified) with httpbin.org, and was getting proper replies. Maybe take a look at your code with httpbin.org and then see if you can track down what's wrong with your service.

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.hpp"
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent), manager(this) {
  load();
}

void MainWindow::load() {
  const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("http://httpbin.org/xml"));

  QNetworkReply* reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(url));

  connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, [this, reply]() {
    replyFinished(reply);
  });

  qDebug() << reply->readAll(); // The reply won't be ready by now, so
                                // testing here isn't very helpful.
}

void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply) {
  qDebug() << reply->readAll();
  reply->deleteLater();
}
```

MainWindow.hpp

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_HPP
#define MAINWINDOW_HPP

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

 public slots:
  void load();
  void replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply);

 private:
  QNetworkAccessManager manager;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_HPP
```

main.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.hpp"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

network.pro

```
QT += core gui widgets network

TARGET = network
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
  main.cpp \
  MainWindow.cpp

HEADERS += MainWindow.hpp
```

Comment: i test your solution but didn't work :( in Qt 5.6. Can you improve your anwer please? thanks :)